# CreateSymmetricKey issues in UWP application/portable library

Tags: c#, cryptography, uwp, portable-class-library

I have the following function I use to create a symmetric key. This code is used both on a Windows 10 UWP app and inside a portable library with profile7.

```
public bool Initialize( string securityKey ) {

  byte[] saltBytes = new byte[256];
  byte[] codeBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( securityKey );
  for ( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {
    saltBytes[i] = codeBytes[i % codeBytes.Length];
  }

  IBuffer bufferSalt = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray( saltBytes );

  _symmetricProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm( SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7 );
  _serverSessionKey = _symmetricProvider.CreateSymmetricKey( bufferSalt );

  int key = _serverSessionKey.GetHashCode();

  return true;
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the key hash is different if I run the code directly from the app or from an app that uses the portable library. And of course encrypted data from the portable library does not decrypt in the app.

I do not require a really strong mechanism for generating the key, only a way to create the same key both on Windows and Android (that's why I use portable version) from a shared string.

I've already used the available key derivation functions in Windows.Security.Cryptography namespace but still got same issues: generated keys from same seed with same generation parameteres are different on different platforms. The above code was intended to just verify if the CreateSymmetricKey produces same key if supplied with same data and this seems not the case, so I'm trying to find out what's wrong or if there's some other mechanisms I can use to have same result

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Suggestion: Add the comment information to the question for completeness in one place and delete the comment.

Comment: I'm not sure that CryptographicKey overrides GetHashCode, so using it to test for equality might not be valid. You'd really need to Export the value and read it directly, or transform something with it and compare the results...

Comment: @bartonjs exporting symmetric keys returns an "not implemented" exception inside portable library.